# Sharepoint Site columns how do i add a year in our column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, lookup-column, column, choice-field

I want to add 2019 to 2020 look upon our `YEAR` column. Please assist

[image]

Comment: Hello @Phumlani Mngomezulu, 1. Is the below answer helped you? 2. do you need any further clarification? if no, please mark the answer as accepted to close this question. Please check also [Tour](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour) to know how can you accept the correct answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a `Choice Filed` or `Lookup Filed`,

Regardless of its type, you can add new values as the following:

- First, Exit `Quick Edit` Mode, Open List > From the above ribbon, click **List Settings**.
- Below `columns` section, Click on the **Column Name** to edit it.

  - In case it's a **choice field**, just scroll down and add your new entries as shown below.

    [image]
  - In case it's a **lookup field**, check the list name

    [image]

    - Go to site content > search about the list > add a new item > add the year value